# Query where another row's datetime is over 1 hour ago

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run this query against `tickets` table. `ticket_updates` table contains rows matching `tickets.ticketnumber = ticket_updates.ticketnumber`

I want to check for rows in `tickets` where the last row in `ticket_updates.datetime` is >= 1 hour ago.

The problem with the below is that it's picking up rows from `ticket_updates` where `datetime` is over 1 hour ago, because its in my WHERE clause, so it's completely ignoring the most recent row which in fact is only 10 minutes ago.

So I think I need to remote the `datetime` from my WHERE clause, but I'm not sure what to add to make it work.

```
SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE
(
    status = 'Pending Response' AND
    ticketnumber IN
    (
        SELECT ticketnumber FROM ticket_updates WHERE
        type = 'customer_reminder_flag' AND
        datetime < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY
    )
) OR
(
    status = 'Pending Completion' AND
    ticketnumber IN (
        SELECT ticketnumber FROM ticket_updates WHERE
            type = 'update' AND
            datetime < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
        ORDER BY datetime DESC
    )
)
```

Comment: I must say I don't understand problem, its always helpful to add sample data and desired result, you can make fiddle in www.db-fiddle.com  for example...

Comment: I'm rather lost.  Your question is about hours, but the sample code has days.  Similarly status columns are used in the code but are not mentioned in the problem statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-write your query using `EXISTS` as follows:

```
SELECT t.* 
  FROM tickets t join ticket_updates tu on t.ticketnumber = tu.ticketnumber 
 WHERE t.status = 'Pending Completion' 
   AND tu.type = 'update' 
   AND tu.datetime < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
   AND NOT EXISTS 
       (SELECT 1 FROM ticket_updates tuu
         WHERE tu.ticketnumber  = tuu.ticketnumber 
           AND tuu.type = 'update' 
           AND tuu.datetime < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
           AND tuu.datetime > tu.datetime
       )
```

If you are running on mysql 8.0+ then you can use analytical function as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT t.*, row_number() over (partition by tu.ticketnumber order by tu.datetime) as rn 
  FROM tickets t join ticket_updates tu on t.ticketnumber = tu.ticketnumber 
 WHERE t.status = 'Pending Completion' 
   AND tu.type = 'update' 
   AND tu.datetime < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR) t
 WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: using the first query, is the JOIN required or could I get away without it?

Comment: Using first query, JOIN is required. better you go with second query if you are on mysql 8.0 or higher

Comment: ok, only reason i asked is because I missed some part of my original query out (i know i shouldnt have, but i thought it would just be the clause i needed to work on - lesson learnt :) ) - see updated query which contains another clause (this one works fine)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to check for rows in tickets where the last row in ticket_updates.datetime is >= 1 hour ago.

For this problem statement, the code would use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from tickets t
where not exists (select 1
                  from ticket_updates tu
                  where tu.ticketnumber = t.ticketnumber and
                        tu.datetime > now() - interval 1 hour
                 );
```

This returns tickets that have had more than one hour since the last update.

It is unclear to me what this problem statement has to do with the code you have shown.